# GPG Hanging When Generating a Key

Tags: linux, gnupg

I tried to follow the GitLab instructions to general GPG keys on a `MX 21.1 Wildflower` (based on Debian 11, codename bullseye) Virtual Box VM (host machine Windows 10).

[GitLab Instructions](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/gpg_signed_commits/#create-a-gpg-key)

I decided on using RSA and RSA, 4096 bit key as instructed.

```
gpg2 --full-gen-key --debug-all
gpg: reading options from '[cmdline]'
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.27; Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

gpg: enabled debug flags: packet mpi crypto filter iobuf memory cache memstat trust hashing ipc clock lookup extprog
gpg: DBG: [not enabled in the source] start
gpg: directory '/home/myhome/.gnupg' created
gpg: DBG: fd_cache_invalidate (/home/myhome/.gnupg/pubring.kbx)
gpg: DBG: iobuf-1.0: open '/home/myhome/.gnupg/pubring.kbx' desc=file_filter(fd) fd=3
gpg: DBG: iobuf-1.0: close 'file_filter(fd)'
gpg: DBG: /home/myhome/.gnupg/pubring.kbx: close fd/handle 3
gpg: DBG: fd_cache_close (/home/myhome/.gnupg/pubring.kbx) new slot created
gpg: DBG: iobuf-*.*: ioctl '/home/myhome/.gnupg/pubring.kbx' invalidate
gpg: DBG: fd_cache_invalidate (/home/myhome/.gnupg/pubring.kbx)
gpg: DBG:                 did (/home/myhome/.gnupg/pubring.kbx)
gpg: keybox '/home/myhome/.gnupg/pubring.kbx' created
Please select what kind of key you want:
   (1) RSA and RSA (default)
   (2) DSA and Elgamal
   (3) DSA (sign only)
   (4) RSA (sign only)
  (14) Existing key from card
Your selection? 
RSA keys may be between 1024 and 4096 bits long.
What keysize do you want? (3072) 4096
Requested keysize is 4096 bits
Please specify how long the key should be valid.
         0 = key does not expire
      <n>  = key expires in n days
      <n>w = key expires in n weeks
      <n>m = key expires in n months
      <n>y = key expires in n years
Key is valid for? (0) 
Key does not expire at all
Is this correct? (y/N) y

GnuPG needs to construct a user ID to identify your key.

Real name: That Name
Email address: my@email.com
Comment: 
You selected this USER-ID:
    "That Name <my@email.com>"

Change (N)ame, (C)omment, (E)mail or (O)kay/(Q)uit? O
We need to generate a lot of random bytes. It is a good idea to perform
some other action (type on the keyboard, move the mouse, utilize the
disks) during the prime generation; this gives the random number
generator a better chance to gain enough entropy.
```

It seems to get stuck on the steps to generate entropy. Despite the steps being dated and the tool being only pseudo random, I tried the following to create entropy:

[GPG Entropy Technique using RNGD](https://delightlylinux.wordpress.com/2015/07/01/is-gpg-hanging-when-generating-a-key/)

Problem is, I tried to let this run for few hours, far past what how long I expect the generation to take and its still stuck.

After I kill the `gpg` process I run the following to clean the state before retrying.

```
$ rm -rf ~/.gnupg/
```

Question is: How do I go about debugging the process?

I know I can get past this probably just using my host machine, Windows 10, to generate the key, but I'm still wondering what is happening in my VM to prevent the process from completing.

For a diagnosis step, I did try re-running the following on a another shell  every few seconds:

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail
```

Seems to be stuck at `256` at all times. Any suggestions on what else I can try?

---

EDIT 1:
I did try the following as well:
https://serverfault.com/questions/214605/gpg-does-not-have-enough-entropy
https://serverfault.com/questions/471412/gpg-gen-key-hangs-at-gaining-enough-entropy-on-centos-6

I did trying to output the stack and it does look to be stuck on a read event, unsure what's it trying to read, as I can `cat /dev/random` and `cat /dev/urandom` on differnt runs when trying to use `rngd` and it seems to continuely output random letters/numbers

```
$ sudo cat /proc/89785/stack 
[<0>] unix_stream_read_generic+0x58d/0x870
[<0>] unix_stream_recvmsg+0x53/0x70
[<0>] sock_read_iter+0x92/0xf0
[<0>] new_sync_read+0x18a/0x1a0
[<0>] vfs_read+0xf4/0x180
[<0>] ksys_read+0xa7/0xe0
[<0>] do_syscall_64+0x33/0x80
[<0>] entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
```

I'll do a more in-depth research later (especially on `strace`), but this is currently what I'm seeing on the stack

Answer (score 0):

Entropy generation is always a challenge in virtual machines, as it's based on "random input" from the environment. However, a virtual machine's I/O is all dictated by the host computer and is only done when absolutely necessary, hence the low entropy.

A common solution for this, if you don't have crazy security requirements, is to install [`haveged`](https://www.issihosts.com/haveged/). It uses the pseudorandom HAVEGE algorithm to inject more entropy into the Linux kernel. Installation and usage is super simple:

```bash
apt-get install haveged
systemctl enable haveged
systemctl start haveged
```

More information about the HAVEGE algorith is available [here](https://www.irisa.fr/caps/projects/hipsor/)

Answer (score 0):

> How do I go about debugging the process?

Looking in `sudo cat /proc/PID/stack` would show where in the kernel that process is currently stuck. The `strace` tool can be useful to see which kernel calls a process makes, e.g. whether it's busy trying to read from /dev/random or waiting on a getrandom() syscall.

Note: GnuPG 2.1.x and later rely on gpg-agent to handle private keys, so instead of inspecting `gpg` itself, you should check what the `gpg-agent` process is doing.

In fact, since you have the 'ipc' debug flag enabled, you *should* be seeing gpg at least attempt to talk to gpg-agent. Use `gpg-connect-agent` to check whether the gpg-agent process is alive and responding. (It should be started by systemd the first time something connects to the socket, or failing that, spawned by gpg itself.)

Also, the process might appear stuck because gpg-agent might be trying to show a graphical "private key passphrase" prompt (for protecting the newly generated key). Sometimes you might be working on console or over SSH, but gpg-agent might still be thinking that you have X11 available, and might be displaying a graphical prompt on a different monitor than you're looking at – try `unset DISPLAY; gpg-connect-agent updatestartuptty /bye` to update its environment.

> Seems to be stuck at 256 at all times.

[That's normal.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/704737/kernel-5-10-119-caused-the-values-of-proc-sys-kernel-random-entropy-avail-and-p) Current Linux kernels have a sufficiently good CSPRNG and no longer perform entropy accounting. Once the kernel's RNG is successfully initialized (which in itself should be faster due to Linux now using a `haveged`-like method by default), /dev/random will provide any amount of data without blocking.